# Generalizing the Quadratic Formula to a Field with Characteristic $\neq 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, quadratics

Here is a definition given by my book:

> Suppose $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c\in F[x]$ with $2a\in F^\times$, and set $\Delta=b^2-4ac$.
>
> 1) If there is a $\delta\in F$ such that $\delta^2=\Delta$, then the roots of $f(x)$ are $\frac{-b\pm\delta}{2a}$.
>
> 2) If there is no such $\delta\in F$, then $f(x)$ has no roots in $F$.

Indeed, this definition seems familiar, and I know that, for polynomials in $\mathbb R[x]$, this can be proven by completing the square. However, how can I generalize it from $\mathbb R[x]$ to $F[x]$ where $F$ can be any field with characteristic $\neq 2$? I'm unsure whether completing the square still works in this case, and the concepts of fields and polynomial arithmetic seem a bit abstract to the mathematically untalented me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Now that this seems to require that $2 \neq 0$ in $F$, that is, $F$ has characteristic other than 2.

Comment: @lisyarus Right! I saw this statement on another post. The book (text) I'm reading is not very well organized and I haven't got to characteristic yet. But I've edited my question anyway. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: If you run through completing the square, you'll see you use nothing but field operations and field axioms, so it works in any field – provided that division by $2a$ is allowed, and the hypotheses you've written explicitly make that OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a little elaboration on the given assumptions and conclusions might be helpful. First of all: what is the characteristic of a field (as you have mentioned in the comments that you have not got to charateristics yet).

The characteristic ${\rm char}~F$ of a field $F$ is the least natural number $n$ such that $n\cdot1=0$. If there is no such $n$ we say that $F$ is of characteristic $0$. An elementary exercise shows that $n$ has to be a prime number, which is due to the fact that a field is in particular a so-called [integral domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain#Definition). This is just the term used for structures where $a\cdot b=0$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$ (an element $x$ for which there exists an element $y$ such that $x\cdot y=0$ is called a zero divisor; an integral domain (and thus a field) has no zero divisors apart from $0$ itself).

> Our familiar fields being $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$ are both of characteristic $0$. On the other hand $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is of characteristic $2$ and in particular here we have $0\equiv2$.

Anyway, the notion of the characteristic is not (explictly) needed here. The crucial assumption is in fact given by $2a\in F^\times$. In general $F^\times$ denotes the (multiplicatively) invertible elements of the field $F$. Well, this is nothing else than all non-zero elements by the field axioms. So we have $F^\times=F\setminus\{0\}$ (this notation becomes useful as soon as not all non-zero elements are forced to be invertible, see [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics))).
We assume that $2a\in F^\times$, so if ${\rm char}~F=2$ we would have $2a\equiv0a=0\in F^\times$ which is a contradiction. Therefore, from our assumption $2a\in F^\times$ it already follows that ${\rm char}~F\neq2$, but that is not important.

Knowing this, we can actually consider an arbitrary quadratic polynomial $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c\in F[x]$ ($a\neq0$) and continue by completing the square
\begin{align*}
ax^2+bx+c&=0\\
x^2+\frac bax+\frac ca&=0&&;a\neq0\\
x^2+\frac bax+\left(\frac b{2a}\right)^2&=\left(\frac b{2a}\right)^2-\frac ca&&;2a\in F^\times\iff 2a\neq0\\
\left(x+\frac b{2a}\right)^2&=\left(\frac b{2a}\right)^2-\frac ca\\
\left(x+\frac b{2a}\right)^2&=\frac{b^2-4ac}{(2a)^2}\tag1
\end{align*}
So far so good. Now we ran into the next issue: can we take the square root without leaving the field $F$? In general not (consider $F=\Bbb Q$ and take $f(x)=x^2-2$). Answering questions like: what do we need to adjoin in order to "solve" (i.e. write as product of linear factors) this and that polynomial; are there fields, where we can always take the square root of any element (can you think of one?); etc. pp. lead to the interesting field of [Galois Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory), but this goes way beyond the scope of this answer.

The assumptions you gave take care of this situation quite easily. Defining the *discriminant* $\Delta=b^2-4ac$ is the essential step. Now we have two cases: either there is a square root of $\Delta$ or there is not. These are precisely the two cases given. If have an element $\delta\in F$ such that $\delta^2=\Delta$ we can take the square root and the usual quadratic formula emerges from $(1)$; if we have no such element, we cannot go further than $(1)$.

> Consider the quadratic polynomial $f(x)=x^2+1\in\Bbb R[x]$. Here we have $a=1$, $b=0$ and $c=1$. Then $\Delta=0^2-1\cdot1=-1$ and, obviously, there is no element $\delta\in\Bbb R$ such that $\delta^2=-1$ (as one should check nevertheless).
>   A more exotic example, consider $f(x)=x^3-3\in\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$. Here $\Delta=3$ but there is not element $\delta\in\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$ such that $\delta^2=3$ as one can check by hand (there are not that many elements in $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$).

Comment: Yes, this elaboration definitely clears all my confusion. I've fixed a minor typo of equation (1). $b^2-4a$ to $b^2-4ac$. As for the "can you think of one" question, $\mathbb{C}$ is an example, right?

Comment: @Skorpion Glad to help! Yes, this is exactly the example I was thinking of. $\Bbb C$ is a so-called [algebraically closed field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field), which says even more: every (real or complex )polynomial can be factored into linear terms over $\Bbb C$ (equivalenty, every (real or complex) polynomial has a root in $\Bbb C$)!